# Accessing a web service programmatically in C#

Tags: java, c#, web-services

I have a JAVA program trying to consume a web service. I am afraid and I am unable to post it here since it was given to me by my client and I am not supposed to post such things anywhere.
I want the same program re-written in C#. I've been trying to do the conversion and still found issues with some classes. What I have on the left hand side is set of Java classes and unfortunately I was able to find the equivalence of only one class.

```
- SOAPConnectionFactory  
- SOAPConnection 
- SOAPMessage    - > SoapMessage  
- SOAPPart   
- SOAPBody
- SOAPElement
- SOAPEnvelope
- MessageFactory
```

Can someone help me to locate the C# equivalence of the above classes ?

Comment: Its really hard to find one-to-one equivalent in .NET...better to frame your question in the way what you want to achieve

Comment: I tried a lot !

Answer (score 1):

There is no direct equivalent to those classes. The framework that is used to connect to soap services is different in .NET compared to Java (obviously). To connect to a web service in a C# project, you have to add a service reference to the SOAP service. In Visual Studio you can do that in the solution explorer by right-clicking on the project that accesses the service and select "Add->Service Reference..." from the context menu. This will create proxy classes for your webservice. You can then rewrite service access to use those proxies.